# nvcc fatal : Unknown option 'pthread'

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am trying to install Elemental. I cloned it from the GitHub directory. Made a build directory and ran `cmake` command in it. But when I do a make, it shows the following error message:

> [ 73%] Linking CUDA device code
>   CMakeFiles/EntrywiseMap.dir/cmake_device_link.o
>
> nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'pthread'
>   tests/CMakeFiles/EntrywiseMap.dir/build.make:99: recipe for target
>   'tests/CMakeFiles/EntrywiseMap.dir/cmake_device_link.o' failed
>
> make[2]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/EntrywiseMap.dir/cmake_device_link.o]
>   Error 1
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1506: recipe for target
>   'tests/CMakeFiles/EntrywiseMap.dir/all' failed
>
> make[1]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/EntrywiseMap.dir/all] Error 2
>
> Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

---

I am using ubuntu 18, with cuda 10 and cmake version 3.13.4

Answer (score 2):

What's the version of Cmake? This issue seems to be on CMake 3.12 and fixed on CMake 3.13

Comment: I am using cmake version of 3.13.4

Answer (score 0):

For me moving to the newer version of CMake `3.14.0` helped get past the issue.